# select and mutate using native pipe

Tags: r

I'm rewriting a package to move from using magrittr pipe to native pipe (for fun) and already finding some troubles with regards to placeholders.
My original codes is something like this:

```
new_df<- original_df %>%
select(ncol(original_df)-1,ncol(original_df)) %>% #select the utimate and penultimate column
mutate(new =.[[1]]/.[[2]]*100) #divide one column by another to create a new column.
```

With the new pipe, I have not yet figured out how to deal with .[[]] and mutate.

```
new_df<-original_df|>
select(ncol(original_df)-1,ncol(original_df))|> 
mutate(new =.[[1]]/.[[2]]*100)
```

I've tried mutate (mutate((.) new =.[1]/.[2]*100) with no luck (among many other things!)

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `mutate`  that means that the dply package is loaded and therefore use `%>%` instead. Note that the `|>` does not have a way to refer back to the passed dataframe/argument, while `mutate/tidyverse` uses the dot `.`. eg `head(iris) %>%do.call(paste, .)` will work, but there is no way to directly replace the pipe with the native pipe unless you write a function

Comment: If you desire to use native pipes then also try to learn base functions eg `subset` instead of `select`, `transform` instead of `mutate` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `mutate` code to something like

```
mtcars |>
  select(ncol(mtcars)-1, ncol(mtcars)) |>
  mutate(new = cur_data()[[1]]/cur_data()[[2]]*100)
```

This will be safer because `curr_data` will with with `group_by` where as the old method of `.[[1]]` would not. You can use this more robust selection with either pipe.